# Accessing variable in SQL in a dynamic query

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-sql

I am very new to SQL. I want to access a variable dynamically in a select statement.

```
declare @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
declare @tableName varchar(100)
set @tableName='xxxx'

set @sql='select * from ' +@tableName+ 
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql
```

But every time I am executing the above query I am getting an error:

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'EXEC'.
```

Comment: remove the + after @tableName.  Should be +@tableName

Comment: Thanks Rick.It's a silly mistake ..anyways appreciate your help..

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
declare @tableName NVARCHAR(128);
set @tableName='xxxx';

SET @sql = N'select * from ' + QUOTENAME(@tableName)
EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql
```

Use [`QUOTENAME()`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114.aspx) Function when concertinaing passed variables from users to your dynamic sql. It protects you against possible sql injection attack.

Comment: Very slick method of protecting against injection. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You've got an extra plus sign after `@tableName` - remove it:

```
set @sql='select * from ' +@tableName  /*+ */
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql
```

Answer (score 0):

You had one too many plus(+) signs around @table name.
Please note that this method is wide open to an injection attack though.

```
declare @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
declare @tableName varchar(100)
set @tableName='xxxx'

set @sql='select * from ' +@tableName
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql
```